# Which values does this augmented matrix have a solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The augmented matrix is:
$$\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}1&a&0 & 1\\0&1&b & 1\\c&0&1 & 1\end{array}\right]$$

So which values of $a$, $b$, and $c$ does this have a solution? I already know that having $a$, $b$, and $c$ being all zero gives it a unique solution but how could I find any other solutions and are there values that could give this matrix an infinite number of solutions?

Comment: @imranfat : You should not say "infinite solutions" if you mean "infinitely many solutions".  If you had three solutions, and if each one of those were an "infinite solution" (whatever that could be) then you would have infinite solutions, but you would not have infinitely many solutions. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put $-c$ times the first row plus the third row in place of the third row, you get
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & a & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & b & 1\\ 0 & -ac & 1 & 1-c \end{array} \right].
$$
Next, you can put $ac$ times the second row, plus the third row, in place of the third row, and you get
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & a & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & b & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 1+abc & 1-c+ac \end{array} \right].
$$
That will have infinitely many solutions if $1+abc=0$ and $1-c+ac=0$. Can you solve that pair of equations for $a$, $b$, and $c$?

Answer (score 0):

You can row reduce it to
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&0&-ab&1-a\\
0&1&b&1\\
0&0&1+abc&1+ac-c
\end{array}\right)$$
So if $1+abc\neq0$ it has a unique solution.

If on the other hand $1+abc=0$ then it has a solution iff $1+ac-c=0$, in which case it has an (infinite) one dimensional set of solutions.