# For which values a,b,c does the system have a solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

If a system of linear equations has augmented matrix $$[A|\vec{b}]=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & a & 0 & 1\\ 
0 & 1 & b & 1\\ 
c & 0 & 1  & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$$ for which values a, b, c, does the system have a solution? Are there values with a unique solution? If so, give all the values.

So far I have found that c=0 for there to be a solution so that the Rank is 3 = # of equations. My guess is that a and b can be any value, as when I plug them in there is a solution, but apparently I'm supposed to list all values? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Try to reduce it into echelon form and look for the conditions when Rank(A)=Rank(A|b).

Comment: This same question was just asked by one of your classmates http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1944426/which-values-does-this-augmented-matrix-have-a-solution/1944442#1944442

Answer (score 1):

For unique solution, we need$$ \begin{vmatrix}
1 & a & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & b \\ 
c & 0 & 1  
\end{vmatrix} \neq 0$$
This holds if and only if $1+abc \neq 0$.

When $1+abc = 0$:

The system of equations can be written as:
\begin{align*}
x + ay &= 1 \\
y+bz &= 1\\
cx + z &= 1
\end{align*}
Eliminating $z$, we have 
\begin{align*}
x+ay &= 1\\
-bcx + y &= 1-b
\end{align*}
This has no unique solution and the condition for infinitely many solutions is 
$$-bc(1-ay) + y = 1 - b \Rightarrow -bc + (1+abc)y = 1-b \Rightarrow 1-b+bc = 0$$
In this case, $y$ can be arbitrary, $x = 1-ay$ and $z = 1- c(1-ay)$.